# What happens when an event is triggered and page update both take place at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Given I have HTML like this:

```
<a id="google" href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
```

And JavaScript like this:

```
$('#google').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log("Click Click Bang Bang!");
});
```

When I click my <kbd>google</kbd> link, the `click` event fires and the page immediately loads the next link…

What happens if the target URL (google.com) loads before the click event finishes?  If events just fire and complete irrespective of the viewable page updating/changing urls/etc then that's awesome!  BUT if that's not the case, how do you ensure your `click` event runs to completion?

Answer (score 2):

The console.log is `synchronous` call and page is redirected after the completion of the click event. If you have `asynchronous` call in the `click` event then you have to take care that your have to wait for response before leaving the page.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The last part of my question says: how do you ensure your click event runs to completion?  Is there a preferred way of doing this?  thanks!

Comment: @user3084728 it will always run before your gets redirected

Comment: It depends, if you do not have asnc call then click event will get completed before opening a link.

Comment: For asnc call you may prevent the default link behaviour until success or failure

Comment: @adil i'm sorry but I'm a newbie. Any code examples you can provide will be really helpful.

Comment: If you are newbie then you do not have to worry about completion of click event unless you start using async calls in click event handler.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little (lot) more to this than meets the eye.

First, you should really understand event-bubbling.
That is to say, you've set the "click" event-handler to run as soon as the `<a>` element has found a "click" event.

Which means that whatever handlers are given to that object will run before the element tells its parent (who will tell their parent, on and on, until you get to the top of the page).
Switching pages happens at the root-element (`<html>` or `document.documentElement`).

So on the *same* event, the `a.onclick = function () { };` will always happen before the `window.onclick = function () { };` handler, because of bubbling.

**HOWEVER** that only begins to scratch the surface...

If you are running async operations inside of your click-handler, and it's a click on a link, and the browser is going to change pages, then all of your async stuff (server-calls/image-loads/script-loads/etc) are ignored (or cancelled), once the browser reaches the `"unload"` phase (more on that, later).

You would either need to synchronize what you're doing (save to `document.cookie` or `localStorage`, instead of making AJAX calls, et cetera), or manually prevent the `<a>` from telling its parents what happened, using `.stopPropagation()` on the event object, which is passed to the event-handler.

Of course, now that it doesn't tell its parents, it will never reach `window`, so the page will never change...

...so now, in your handler, if you want the page to change, after you've done your async stuff, you have to manually make the page-change happen by setting `window.location = googleEl.href;`, and do so after you're sure all of your async work is done.

...of course, that's not the end of it...  ...when the browser does want to change the page, it also fires a `"beforeunload"` event, and an `"unload"` event you can listen to from `window`. Again, the same async rules apply...
And to make things muddier, only most browsers fire `"beforeunload"`, some don't bother.

So to answer your exact question:
The click-handler fires first, then a few events in between, then `"beforeunload"`, then `"unload"`, then the page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend redirecting through anchor after on click.
therefore :

> ```
> $('#google').on('click', function (e) {
>   console.log("Click Click Bang Bang!");
>   //This would stop from redirecting
>   e.preventDefault();
>   //This will take you to Google after completing the above task
>   window.location.reload = "http://google.com";
> });
> ```

Comment: Why?  can you explain your reasoning please?

Comment: @user3084728 Sure. the reason i put e.preventDefault(); is to stop the link from executing so that you can perform all the operations you want in your click and later lead the control to the desired website after your click completes.