# Async Version: What happens when an event is triggered and page update both take place at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-events

Note:
This is an asynchronous version of this question I asked yesterday: [What happens when an event is triggered and page update both take place at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422241/what-happens-when-an-event-is-triggered-and-page-update-both-take-place-at-the-s/)

Given I have HTML like this:

```
<a id="google" href="http://google.com">Google.com</a>
```

And Javascript like this:

```
$('#google').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  asyncFuncThatLogsAnalytics(this);
  // Do some more
  console.log("Click Click Bang Bang!");
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
});
```

When I click my `Google` link, the `click` event fires and the page immediately loads the next link…

What can I do to ensure all events within the click event have fired/finished BEFORE changing the window's location?

Comment: if asyncFuncThatLogsAnalytics() method returns a promise interface, then use done() or always() method. If not, then make it returns it. I'm not sure google analytics expose such kind of method but a callback should be available, somewhere. Basically, what you want is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Do you have any examples of how the code for a `promise` interface would look?